# Getting the same data from the QuickBooks no matter how I change the qbXML

Tags: qbxml

I just started learning the QuickBooks, able to successfully send the XML requests, but a bit confused about what I get back

I try different request types, CheckQueryRq, VendorQueryRq, InvoiceQueryRq but ALWAYS get back the same identical data

Here are my XML's

```
<xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
<qbxml version=""12.0""?> 
<QBXML>
            <QBXMLMsgsRq onError=""stopOnError"">
                <CheckQueryRq>
                    <IncludeLineItems>true</IncludeLineItems>
                </CheckQueryRq>
            </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>

<xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
<qbxml version=""12.0""?> 
<QBXML>
            <QBXMLMsgsRq onError=""stopOnError"">
                <VendorQueryRq>
                    <IncludeLineItems>true</IncludeLineItems>
                </VendorQueryRq>
            </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>

<xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
<qbxml version=""12.0""?> 
<QBXML>
            <QBXMLMsgsRq onError=""stopOnError"">
                <InvoiceQueryRq>
                  <IncludeLineItems>true</IncludeLineItems>
                </InvoiceQueryRq>
            </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Why do those qb XML's return the same identical data?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer, none of the above XML's were in a correct format, and I was getting the data back from the request while I was supposed to get the data back from the response

Here are the correct XML's

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?qbxml version="7.0"?>
<QBXML>
     <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">
           <CheckQueryRq requestID="0">
            </CheckQueryRq>
     </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?qbxml version="7.0"?>
<QBXML>
     <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">
           <VendorQueryRq requestID="0">
            </VendorQueryRq>
     </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?qbxml version="7.0"?>
<QBXML>
     <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">
           <InvoiceQueryRq requestID="0">
            </InvoiceQueryRq>
     </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```